# Is this DFA correct?

Tags: finite-automata

I'm supposed to construct a DFA which accepts

> { w | w is a word except 'aa' and 'aaa' }

Is this the correct [solution](https://docs.google.com/drawings/pub?id=1jebzHyD265xhFif1OUr8l3YqscQTgGpM2ZiepCs8ZDs&w=1411&h=700)? The **thick** line state is supposed to be the end state.

**EDIT**

Sry, somehow mixed two different exercises. Corrected.

**EDIT 2**

Here's the corrected [solution](https://docs.google.com/drawings/pub?id=1jebzHyD265xhFif1OUr8l3YqscQTgGpM2ZiepCs8ZDs&w=1411&h=700)(?)!

Comment: The hw question as presented might be a little unclear. Does it mean w is a word as long as it *doesn't contain* a substring 'aa' and 'aaa'? Or could it mean it's a match if it's not 'aa' and 'aaa'. eg. w = 'aafoobar' would be a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will leave the answer below intact since it's useful in context.

With your update to the question, and your further update with the proposed solution, it would appear to me that it would be valid. Well done!

========= Old post for historical purposes ===========

Important note: aa is a substring of aaa. So by excluding aa, you automatically exclude aaa and aaaa and aaaaa. This means you can only ever have 1 a in a row.

So whenever you add an a, you need to go to an accept state. Whenever you add an a after that, you need to go to a non accept state that loops forever no matter what.

Below is what I came up with. I do not recommend just... putting it down. Think about this. These problems are very important in training how you think!!! Don't spoil yourself!

S denotes start state
+ on corner denotes accept state
X on corner denotes not accept state

```
 B  +-+  A   +-+  A   X-X  A | B
+---|S| ---> |1| ---> |2| ------+
|   +-+      +-+      X-X       |
+___^ ^___B___|       ^________+

"" - ends on start - okay 
"B" - ends on start - okay 
"A" - ends on 1 - okay 
"AA" - ends on 2 - not accepted 
"BAA" - Stats on S, goes to S, goes to 1, goes to 2 - not accepted.
```

A - moves you down the line toward failure.
B - resets you.
two As in a row and you fail :(

Comment: the OP redefined his question since you posted this.